# Cannot start HornetQ without JMS and JNDI

Tags: hornetq

If I run HornetQ with config\stand-alone\non-clustered config files, the HornetQ server starts up fine.

If I remove the JNDI and JMS sections from the hornetq-beans.xml file:

```
   <!-- JNDI server. Disable this if you don't want JNDI -->
   <bean name="JNDIServer" class="org.jnp.server.Main">
      <property name="namingInfo">
         <inject bean="Naming"/>
      </property>
      <property name="port">1099</property>
      <property name="bindAddress">localhost</property>
      <property name="rmiPort">1098</property>
      <property name="rmiBindAddress">localhost</property>
  </bean>
```

AND

```
   <!-- The JMS server -->
   <bean name="JMSServerManager" class="org.hornetq.jms.server.impl.JMSServerManagerImpl">
      <constructor>         
         <parameter>
            <inject bean="HornetQServer"/>
         </parameter>
      </constructor>
  </bean>
```

I get the server dying immediately. This is the output I get:

```
C:\development\hornetQ\hornetq-2.2.14.Final\bin>run.bat ..\config\custom
A subdirectory or file ..\logs already exists.
***********************************************************************************
"java  -XX:+UseParallelGC  -XX:+AggressiveOpts -XX:+UseFastAccessorMethods -Xms512M -  Xmx1024M -Dhornetq.config.dir=..\config\custom  
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=..\config\custom\logging.properties -java.library.path=. -classpath ..\config\custom;..\schemas\;
C:\development\hornetQ\hornetq-2.2.14.Final\lib\hornetq-bootstrap.jar;C:\development\hornetQ\hornetq-2.2.14.Final\lib\hornetq-core-client-java5.jar;
C:\development\hornetQ\hornetq-2.2.14.Final\lib\hornetq-core-client.jar;C:\development\hornetQ\hornetq-2.2.14.Final\lib\hornetq-core.jar;
```

...etc.

```
***********************************************************************************
* [main] 28-Aug 11:7:22,132 INFO [HornetQBootstrapServer]  Starting HornetQ Server

* [main] 28-Aug 11:7:23,91 WARNING [FileConfigurationParser]  AIO wasn't located on  this platform, it will fall back to using pure Java NIO. If your platform is Linux, install
LibAIO to enable the AIO journal

* [hornetq-shutdown-thread] 28-Aug 11:7:23,147 INFO [HornetQBootstrapServer]  Stopping HornetQ Server...
```

Would appreciate if someone would tell me what I'm doing wrong.